# Why my App is not showing up on tablets in Google Play?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I made an app, works well on phones and tablets in the AVDM, upload the app to Google Play but this is not shown in tablets only in phones. I took some codes of other questions, but still no. I think I need to remove or add a line, my Android Manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pack"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3.1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="100" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>

    <compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can see in the Google Play Developer Panel wich devices your app supports, is the Nexus 7 listed in this list?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things,

You have a uses-feature for telephony, but request not telephony permissions.  If you do not use telephony, remove this line.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` should be inside your `<activity>` block.

Next,

```
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="100"
```

From

> If your application properly resizes for smaller screen sizes (down to
>   the small size or a minimum width of 320dp), you do not need to use
>   this attribute.
>
> Caution: The Android system does not pay attention to this attribute,
>   so it does not affect how your application behaves at runtime.
>   Instead, it is used to enable filtering for your application on
>   services such as Google Play. However, Google Play currently does not
>   support this attribute for filtering (on Android 3.2), so you should
>   continue using the other size attributes if your application does not
>   support small screens.

Or, from the same source --

```
android:resizeable="true"
```

> Indicates whether the application is resizeable for different screen
>   sizes. This attribute is true, by default. If set false, the system
>   will run your application in screen compatibility mode on large
>   screens.
>
> This attribute is deprecated. It was introduced to help applications
>   transition from Android 1.5 to 1.6, when support for multiple screens
>   was first introduced. You should not use it.